# How to sync/backup files whenever change is detected?

Tags: shell-script, rsync, backup, synchronization

I have two partition, one for use and one for backup. So, is there any tool for syncing the folder from first partition to second. Also, the tool should sync immediately whenever a change is made to file or folder. If immediate sync is not possible how do i automate my task, to sync properly
Suppose i have folder mounted `/dev/sda6` (windows) to `window` folder and running linux. I want to backup/sync `/root/*` to `/media/window/backup` and whenever i add or delete a file or folder in `/root/*` ,`/media/window/backup` should be updated.

Comment: To better understand your question: synchronized storage volumes don't actually provide backup, because a single (careless or malicious) action can remove data from both of them. Data duplication is used to protect it from failures (e.g. RAID), but there is usually only one copy presented to the user (and not two, independent partitions). What exactly is your use case? If it's backup, syncing is probably not what you should look for.

Comment: I m backup up sorry not syncing. Also, one is ntfs (window ) partition and other is ext4, @fra-san

Comment: ".. _whenever I add or delete a file ... `backup` should be updated_": how do you plan to recover files that are deleted or changed by mistake if the copy is deleted or changed too? (This is why I brought up the distinction between synchronizaton and backup). To have a real backup you need to keep at least one copy of an older version of the same file, including deleted files.

Comment: oh yes, hmm you are right

Comment: sorry for the question , i m foolish, i will just backup once a month, thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this:

1. https://linuxhint.com/inotofy-rsync-bash-live-backups/
2. https://www.b247.eu.org/2019/09/restic-incron-inotify-continuous-backup-folder-change.html

and this topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/7969/is-there-a-working-linux-backup-solution-that-uses-inotify

Or you can run `rsync` using `cron`.

Comment: Ok i will check out, hmm i will try to develop a crontab or use intofiy or something else, hmm good

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after all i got a plan. I want backup/sync but if i delete i m gone.
So, pseudocode looks something like this

```bsh
while inotify create/modify #executes command if create/modify 
do
   if `du source` is greater than `du destination` then #size of source is gt than dest
      rsync source/ dest -av
done
```

Finally did it

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ `pgrep -f $0` != "$$" ]]; then
    echo "Exiting"
    exit
fi
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create /root/MachineYadav 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
do
    echo "0" > /tmp/KaliLinuxBackup
    clear && sleep 1.5 && echo "Backing up" && sleep 0.5
    if [[ `du -s /root/MachineYadav/ | awk '{print $1}'` -gt `du -s /root/Mount/Window/Kali-Mirror | awk '{print $1}'` ]]; then
        echo "1" > /tmp/KaliLinuxBackup
        rsync /root/MachineYadav/ /root/Mount/Window/Kali-Mirror/ -av 
    fi
    clear && echo "Finishing" && sleep 0.5
done
```

I will have similar implementation along with some modification. Thanks @Artem S. Tashkinov and @fra-san